# Reuseable buffer with variable length

Tags: c#, memory-management

- I'm grabbing frames from camera or video file.
- From each frame (Bitmap) I want to crop rectangle and save it in memory.
- When processing new frame I don't need the old cropped rectangle anymore. I can overwrite it with new cropped rectangle.

Obviously, I can't create new byte array for each frame and rely on Garbage Collection, because I would easily go out of memory or at least the memory would be very fragmented. I need to reuse some buffer.

It would be ease if the size of cropped rectangles was constant, but it may be different in each frame (image object tracking in video).

**Is there any API that could help me with the memory management?** I tried to reuse `MemoryStream`, but I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing it:

```
if (memoryStream == null)
{
   memoryStream = new MemoryStream(1024*10);
}
else
{
   memoryStream.Position=0;   //
   memoryStream.SetLength(0); //"clear" memoryStream, but hopefully keeps underlying buffer allocated/
}

croppedBitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: "Obviously, I can't ... rely on Garbage Collection" - oh, so you've tried that and measured it? Care to share the results? Or you've *assumed* that GC won't do the job?

Comment: I was getting out of memory exception and high memory usage (hundreds of megabytes) after couple of seconds

Comment: Please try to explain precisely what you're trying to do.  How many frames do you need to store in memory, for example?

Comment: @Liero - ah, so you mean you have a memory leak, and rather than fix that, you're going to blame the GC?

Comment: @ Robinson - I want to save only the last cropped image in memory.
@Damien_The_Unbeliever: I'm not blaming GC. And I don't have memory leak, exactly. But that would require GC to clean memory every second and that is not efficient. You can easily run out of memory if you allocate large objects to often even if you dispose them or don't keep references to them. The other thing is, that if GC colletcs too frequently, it moves lot of other objects to higher generation with is also not healthy, imho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options:

1. You could save the image in memory as a `Bitmap`. There isn't really a need to serialize it as a PNG. You can reuse that `Bitmap` object.
2. You could write your own `MemoryStream`-like stream that reuses the same buffer forever.

Comment: the `croppedBitmap` is acually `System.Drawing.Bitmap` object. the problem is, that this Bitmap does't not own the underaying bitmap data. If I dont save it (does not matter in what format - png, or raw), the data are changing under my eyes as I grab new frames. The reason is, that the croppedBitmap just points to the same memory as the buffer where entire frame are loaded (by EmguCV in this case)

Comment: OK, create a second bitmap that you own and use a Graphics object to copy over the pixels that you need to save. Actually, the GC load from creating tons of bitmaps is very low if you dispose of them quickly. A Bitmap object is just a few bytes + a huge unmanaged buffer.

Comment: ok, but that would allocate and release huge unmanaged buffer in each frame and that is expensive, isn't it?

Comment: Then don't release it every frame. Reuse the bitmap. (It's actually not that expensive, it's a memset(0)). Does this answer your question? Are there any issues remaining that you cannot solve?

Comment: hmm, reusing bitmap makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could assume that the cropped rectangle will never be bigger than the size of the full image, allocate that, and just do some bookkeeping on how much of the buffer you're currently using.

Alternatively, you could have an array that you [grow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) but never shrink, and, depending on the granularity of that growing, you won't have too many reallocations.

You can take a look at [`MemoryStream.cs`](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/IO/MemoryStream@cs/1305376/MemoryStream@cs) to see how they deal with changes in capacity. Look at `EnsureCapacity()`, if I read it correctly, it will only allocate a new array when expanding (the array is allocated in the setter for `Capacity`). Disclaimer: I'm not sure whether that's the original source for `MemoryStream`.

Comment: `array that you grow but never shrink` - yes, that exactly what I'm looking for. It seems that memoryStream does exactly this, but there is no guarantee, so I was wondering whether there is such class already. moreover I need to store length of current data somewhere.

Comment: I was looking at MemoryStream dissasembled sources and came to the same conclusion